# Предлоги перед наречиями

Tags: предлоги

Здравствуйте, помогите, пожалуйста! Как правильно: Зашёл в ещё одну комнату или Зашёл ещё в одну комнату? Живёт в очень красивом доме или Живёт очень в красивом доме. Коллега утверждает, что перед наречиями предлоги не употребляются. Очень надеюсь на скорый ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Зашёл ещё в одну комнату. Живёт в очень красивом доме.

Предлоги не относятся к наречию, а писаться могут перед любой частью речи, лишь бы легко произносились (когда-то был закон сингармонизма) и был понятен смысл. *Мимо плотно стоящих домов* - предлог "мимо" перед наречием, но относится к сущ. "домов".

Comment: Спасибо! Я согласна с вами. Есть случаи, когда предлог не употребишь после наречия, может поменяться смысл. Например, "в очень интересное время", "в легко решаемой задаче". Но я не могла найти объяснения. Искала и на Грамоте, и в справочниках. Но такого правила не нашла. Хотелось бы ясности, знать, существует ли такое правило.

Comment: Нужно искать теорию словосочетания. Здесь трёхчленное сочетание "в (легко решаемой) задаче", из которого вычленяются два:"в решаемой задаче", "легко решаемой".